# Locales are not changing fullcalendar language

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar

I have a system with Django. In my template, the lasts scripts are:

```
<script src="{% static 'plugins/moment/min/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar.min.js' %}" ></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/fullcalendar/js/locale-all.js' %}" ></script>
{% block extra_footer %}{% endblock %}
```

In my page, I start the calendar as [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale), like this:

```
{% block extra_footer %}
    <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    lang: '{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}',
                    });

             });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I inspect html code, the LANGUAGE_CODE is ok (for exemple: fr). But the calendar just appears in English, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

That setting is renamed to `locale` in recent versions:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale

For example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  locale: 'fr'
});
```